Pydantic Generic Basemodel Validation Error
Pydantic Generic BaseModels fails unexpectedly when validating python instances but succeeds when validating the same data as a dictionary.
Python: 3.11.8
Pydantic: 2.7.1
Here is the Generic Model:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel

U = TypeVar("U")


class M1(BaseModel, Generic[U]):
    a: list[U]
    b: list[U]


class M2(BaseModel):
    a: str
    m1: M1[int]

It works when validating a raw dictionary:
m2 = M2.model_validate(
    {
        "a": "s",
        "m1": {
            "a": [1],
            "b": [2]
        }
    }
)

However, it does not work when using python types:
m2 = M2(
    a="s",
    m1=M1(
        a=[1],
        b=[2]
    )
)  # fails :(

Interestingly enough, the following also fails:
m2 = M2.model_validate(
    dict(
        a="s",
        m1=M1(
            a=[1],
            b=[2]
        )
    )
)


This is entirely expected behavior. As M1 is a generic type it needs to be declared with the corresponding type to be used. If I copy and paste your example:
m2 = M2(
    a="s",
    m1=M1(
        a=[1],
        b=[2]
    )
)  # fails :(

It fails with:
ValidationError: 1 validation error for M2
m1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of M1[int] [type=model_type, input_value=M1(a=[1], b=[2]), input_type=M1]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/model_type

The important detail here is "instance of M1[int]". So when just instantiating M1 without declaring its type, the instance is of type M1, which is not the same type as M1[int]. However M2 explicitly expects M1[int], so the following just works fine:
m2 = M2(
    a="s",
    m1=M1[int](
        a=[1],
        b=[2]
    )
)  # validates correctly

When you just validate from the dictionary it works fine because Pydantic relies on the default type declared in M2.m1, which is again M1[int].
Now the question is what kind of behavior you would like to achieve. So which types should be allowed for M1? Maybe you have to work with a union of types or similar...
I hope this helps!
